# How to subset a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data set like this

```
a <- data.frame(var1 = c("patientA", "patientA", "patientA", "patientB", "patientB", "patientB", "patientB"),
                var2 = as.Date(c("2015-01-02","2015-01-04","2015-02-02","2015-02-06","2015-01-02","2015-01-07","2015-04-02")),
                var3 = c(F, T, F, F, F, T, F)               
                )
sequ <- rle(as.character(a$var1))
a$sequ <- sequence(sequ$lengths)
```

producing

```
> a
      var1       var2  var3 sequ
1 patientA 2015-01-02 FALSE    1
2 patientA 2015-01-04  TRUE    2
3 patientA 2015-02-02 FALSE    3
4 patientB 2015-02-06 FALSE    1
5 patientB 2015-01-02 FALSE    2
6 patientB 2015-01-07  TRUE    3
7 patientB 2015-04-02 FALSE    4
```

How can I subset/filter this data set so that I get all the rows which var3 == TRUE and var2 date value is greater than in the row where var3 == TRUE (by patient, var1? I tried

```
subset(a, (var3 == TRUE) & (var2 > var3))
```

but this does not produce a correct result set. The correct one is

```
#       var1       var2  var3 sequ
# 1 patientA 2015-01-04  TRUE    2
# 2 patientA 2015-02-02 FALSE    3
# 3 patientB 2015-02-06 FALSE    1
# 4 patientB 2015-01-07  TRUE    3
# 5 patientB 2015-04-02 FALSE    4
```

Comment: Your desired output is not very clear. Do you want *all* the dates that come after `var3 == TRUE` if they are bigger? What happens if there several `var3 == TRUE` per patient?

Comment: Yes, I want the row TRUE included in the results set and also the rows where var3 is FALSE but the dates are bigger than the TRUE row. In my data set there is only one TRUE row per patient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try with `data.table`.  Here, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(a)`), grouped by 'var1', we  get a logical index for 'var2' elements that are greater than or equal to corresponding 'var2' elements for which 'var3' is TRUE and subset the dataset `.SD`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[,.SD[var2 >= var2[var3]], var1]
#       var1       var2  var3 sequ
#1: patientA 2015-01-04  TRUE    2
#2: patientA 2015-02-02 FALSE    3
#3: patientB 2015-02-06 FALSE    1
#4: patientB 2015-01-07  TRUE    3
#5: patientB 2015-04-02 FALSE    4
```

An option using `base R` (assuming that the data is ordered by 'var1')

```
a[with(a, var2>=rep(var2[var3], table(var1))),]
#      var1       var2  var3 sequ
#2 patientA 2015-01-04  TRUE    2
#3 patientA 2015-02-02 FALSE    3
#4 patientB 2015-02-06 FALSE    1
#6 patientB 2015-01-07  TRUE    3
#7 patientB 2015-04-02 FALSE    4
```

Comment: @AlexA.  Sure, it happens to me also.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This produces the correct result set. Is there a way to do this using base R? I'm not aware of data.table syntax.

Comment: @jrara Updated with a base R option

Answer (score 4):

I add a column with the date when `var3` is `TRUE`, filter based on it, then drop it at the end.

```
library(dplyr)

a %>% group_by(var1)%>%
    mutate(truedate = first(var2[var3])) %>%
    filter(var2 >= truedate) %>%
    select(-truedate)

# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: var1

#       var1       var2  var3 sequ
# 1 patientA 2015-01-04  TRUE    2
# 2 patientA 2015-02-02 FALSE    3
# 3 patientB 2015-02-06 FALSE    1
# 4 patientB 2015-01-07  TRUE    3
# 5 patientB 2015-04-02 FALSE    4
```

Answer (score 3):

*A base-R solution*: First, don't bother with your `rle`/`sequ` thing. Instead, sort your data:

```
a <- a[order(a$var1,a$var2),]
```

Find the selected rows:

```
myrows <- tapply(
  1:nrow(a),
  a$var1,
  function(ivec){
    istar <- ivec[a$var3[ivec]]
    ivec[ivec>=istar]
  })
```

Subset with `a[unlist(myrows),]`.

Comment: I added another base R option though I am not sure whether there are any edge cases for that :-)

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I just saw that after posting. Despite also being base-R, glad to see mine's not quite a dupe: no one else insisted that the OP sort :)